# MvvmCross Finaliser called on MvxFluentBindingDescription

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a MvvmCross app. I have a view with a text field and a button, and I can't tap on that text field to get it to focus, or on the button to get it to submit. If I call becomeFirstResponder on the text field in code, then I can get it to focus and I can then type into it.

I have other views with text fields and buttons working fine. Disabling all data binding for this view has no effect.

When this particular view loads, I see this message in the console:

Finaliser called on MvxFluentBindingDescription`2 - suggests that  Apply() was never called

I am calling Apply on the binding set.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    BoundTableViewSource.Create(BindingContext, () => ExpensesTable);

    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<BudgetTrackerView, BudgetTrackerViewModel>();

    set.Bind (MonthlyIncomeText).To (vm => vm.MonthlyIncome);
    set.Bind (CalculateButton).To (vm => vm.Calculate);
    set.Bind (SendForReviewButton).To (vm => vm.SubmitForReview);

    set.Apply ();

    CalculateButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        MonthlyIncomeText.ResignFirstResponder();
    };
}
```

Has anyone seen this message in the console before?

Comment: Are you able to post your code?

Comment: @IainSmith added code, let me know if you would like more. I'm not sure where to focus on since I don't know what's causing the message.

Comment: u got solution?